# Bash - How to know my Linux server IP adress?

Tags: bash, ip, command-line-interface

Is there a way to echo **only** the server ip adress from Bash? I am on a Linux/Debian6.

My intent is to write to "/etc/hosts" the pair domain_name IP for each new domain I register in the server.

As this bash script will be opened for public use, I am trying to find a way of getting this information via cli.

**CONCLUSION:**

This is the final code, based on the clues my friends helped me with:

```
newhost() {
    DMN=$1
    X=`ifconfig | grep Bcast`
    Y=`echo "${X#*:}"`
    DNS=`echo "${Y%\  B*}"` # server DNS(207.112.37.222)
    H='/etc/hosts' #hostfile
    PAIR="$DNS\t$DMN"
    if grep -i --silent "$DMN" "$H"; then
        echo -e "$DMN already exists in $H"
    else
        bash <<EOF
echo -e "$PAIR" >> "$H"
EOF
        echo -e "$PAIR added to $H"
    fi
}
```

*By the way, Isn't it funny that some born-already-smart dudes voted to close the question?*

Thanks.

Comment: You got some more info for us? Are you on the server which you want the IP for? In other words, is it the local IP you are interested in? And a computer normally have more than one IP (for instance the loopback IP, and the internet IP), and IPv4 or IPv6? And is the server behind NAT?

Comment: You can also check /proc/net/tcp, reading the "local_address" field:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use:

`ifconfig` - your ip will be after the `inet addr:` in this case `1.1.1.1`

sample output:

```
root@server [~]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0A:E4:89:0B:97
          inet addr:1.1.1.1  Bcast:1.1.1.63  Mask:255.255.255.192
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1/or modify
          RX packets:14804377317 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11766937374 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:13799286299902 (12.5 TiB)  TX bytes:4891709752100 (4.4 TiB)
          Interrupt:169 Memory:fa000000-fa012800  will be useful,
```

http://www.debianadmin.com/network-interface-configuration-using-ifconfig.html

Comment: the question is about ONLY the ip, and ifconfig is a old tool, today you should use `ip`

Comment: "ifconfig" is a perfectly appropriate answer for "ip", dude!

Comment: [...]Most network configuration manuals still refer to ifconfig and route as the primary network configuration tools, but ifconfig is known to behave inadequately in modern network environments. They should be deprecated, but most distros still include them. Most network configuration systems make use of ifconfig and thus provide a limited feature set. The /etc/net project aims to support most modern network technologies, as it doesn't use ifconfig and allows a system administrator to make use of all iproute2 features, including traffic control.[...] Source: iproute2 manifest

Comment: @pst : "ifconfig only returns the local IP address" what ??? hey dude, don't post comments without having a clue of what you're talking about.

Comment: @Tuga See the IP address reported? That belongs to a *local interface*. Please try to be more civil.

Answer (score 2):

```
ip -4 a l dev $DEVICE  | grep inet | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

replace $DEVICE with the device name. `eth0` should be the right in the most cases

Comment: ifconfig is more portable (virtually all *nix platforms, as well as all Linux distros), has more information, and it's arguably easier to use.  If you have to remember only ONE command, I'd remember "ifconfig" (not "ip").

Comment: And if the user doesn't know the device name ?

Comment: again: The question was about display ONLY the ip. So i think he nows which device he should use. I mentioned `eth0` as default. alAnd ifconfig is old, not usable in many modern setups, and its not all in one command: `ip address`, `ip route`, its more logical at all. The last update for "ifconfig" was 2001 according to the project page. Any other release is a distribution specific patchset. If you need a tool that behaves the same way on all distros, you have to use `ip`

Comment: This is a very smart solution, no doubt: `ip -4 a l dev eth0 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2 }'`

Comment: Some of us have moved beyond the old grep + awk + pipe patterns. Here's another way to do it, and it's a more exact answer because it returns only the IP without the subnet: `perl -e 'for(\`ip -4 a l dev eth0\`){print $1 if (/inet ([.0-9]+)\//)}'`